# Requirements with Alternatives

Tags: system-requirements

In the project I am currently working in, the requirements is on this form:

1. The system must ...
2. The system must ...

It works fine as long as there are no alternative scenario. But how should I write if the system work differently depending on what happens?

```
if ScenarioA Then do This
elseif ScenarioB Then do That
```

Comment: This probably belongs on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) rather than here, seeing has how it's not strictly programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try User Story?

User Stories (opposed to requirements) are brief statements of intent that describe something the system needs to do for some user.

**As a** user closing the application, **I want** to be prompted to save anything that has changed since the last save **so that** I can preserve useful work and discard erroneous work.

> 1. For scenarioA do this
> 2. For scenarioB do that

1. **As a** user doing scenarioA, **I want** this, **so that** I can open my application.
2. **As a** user doing scenarioB, **I want** that, **so that** I can close my application.

Comment: The question was about requirements, not user stories. Moreover, you can't switch to user story if it makes life easier. Requirements are **derived** from user stories and these 2 terms aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing requirements and design (more specifically, use cases). Requirements describe the high-level functionality that the system should be able to provide.
Use cases are derivatives of the requirements.
So your requirements can be:

```
1. For scenarioA do this
2. For scenarioB do that
```

Note, the requirements are context-free and essentially describe capabilities.

And from these requirements a use case (or even several) describing a certain dynamic behavior can be defined:

```
a. Step 1
b. Step 2
...
n. [ScenarioA] do this
n1. [ScenarioB] do that (alternate path)
...
```

Here, the `n` and `n1` steps are defined in scope of the use case context and have not meaning otherwise.